# Netbeans and using wildcards on bootstrap --cp:a

Tags: java, netbeans, classloader, javafx, netbeans-6.9

We currently have a custom startup class for our netbeans-platform application, that requires JavaFX 2.0 on the bootstrap classpath.

It is loaded with `-Dnetbeans.mainclass=com.splash.CustomStartup --cp:a ".\ourApp\modules\ext\com.oracle\javafx-jar-2.1-b09;.\ourApp\modules\splash\customSplash.jar"`

Is there a way to load those .jars using wildcards so when the version changes or we need more dependencies, we don’t need to modify the startup parameters? I have tried multiple combinations as `\*.jar` but couldn't get any to work.

Additional info: [The Definitive Guide to Netbeans Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430241012) says those parameters are parsed and loaded using [Classloader#getSystemResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Note that JavaFX will be distributed as part of the platform from 7u4 onwards, so don't forget to test the edge cases where people have both a pre-bundled JavaFX and a new, shiny version which came with a JDK/JRE upgrade.